# How Can I run a .bat file from Excel?

Tags: batch-file, xls

I have 5 batch files at different locations and I want to run them through Excel like below:

```
F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD 
Batch1.bat, Batch2.bat, Batch4.bat

F:\Financial\Data\Reports\AccountPnlMTD
Batch5.bat, Batch6.bat, Batch7.bat
```

I want to run batch files using excel by a macro..excel macro shuld call the .bat batch files where they are sited and shuld run. Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a batch file via a macro VBA script. For example:

```
Sub RunBatch()
    Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD\Batch1.bat", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

You can use a worksheet change event to create a drop down box. Something like below.

Change the range to whichever cell displays the results of the dropdown box, and change the Macro names. Also, this code would be placed in the code for the worksheet, not a new module.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    Select Case Target.Range("A1").Value 
    Case "First macro Name" 
        Call First_Marco 
    Case "Second macro Name" 
        Call Second_Marco 
    Case "Third macro Name" 
        Call Third_Marco 
    Case "Fourth macro Name" 
        Call Fourth_Marco 
    End Select 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx..Dtmland. I want to run by salecting one by one. (In a dropdown box, where I can salet .bat file & can run).